# eBay API: Expired IAF token

Tags: oauth, token, ebay-api

I'm trying to use the eBay Trading API. When I tested on sandbox, everything was working fine. But when I switched to Production, I'm getting an `Expired IAF token` error. I'm getting the token through eBay Sign-In. The response I'm getting from the Sign-In is

```
{ 
  "code": "v^1.1#i^1#p^3#f^0#r^1#I^3#t^U......EzMDU1REQ5QzQyRjZfMl8xI0VeMjYw",
  "expires_in": 299
}
```

I'm using OAuth2 and not Auth'n'Auth

I've tried connecting to the most basic Trading API endpoint through the eBay API explorer, but I'm still getting the `Expired token` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Turns out that the token I was getting from eBay Sign-In had to be exchanged for an actual Access Token.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).